# How to move selected card to the middle of the screen, and if the selected card is the first or last, it will show fully?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So i made a carousel that show cards of 3 cards subscription. How to move selected card to the middle of the screen automatically. And if i the select card the first or the third, it will show just fully and no need to be in the middle?

Currently if I click the 6-month subs card, it got selected but not fully show up. I want to make it smoothly move to the left so it the card shows up fully like the second picture. I tried the translateX() on CSS but it didn't make my second selected card straight in the middle.

I'm not sure how to implement this? Please help. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {default as style} from './SubscriptionCard.scss.json';
import './SubscriptionCard.scss';
import {cl} from 'lincd/lib/utils/ClassNames';

interface SubscriptionCardProps {
  review?: string;
  month: number;
  monthlyPrice: number;
  totalPrice: number;
  discount?: number;
  isSelected: boolean;
  onSelect?;
}

const SubscriptionCard = ({
  review,
  month,
  monthlyPrice,
  totalPrice,
  discount,
  isSelected,
  onSelect,
}: SubscriptionCardProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={cl(style.card, isSelected && style.selected)}
      onClick={onSelect}
    >
      {isSelected && (
        <img
          className={style.checkmark}
          src="images/checkmark_gold.svg"
          alt="icon"
        />
      )}
      {review && <p className={style.review}>{review}</p>}
      <div className={style.text}>
        <p className={style.priceTitle}>{month} Month</p>
        <div className={style.priceContainer}>
          <p className={style.monthlyPrice}>${monthlyPrice}/mo</p>
          <p className={style.totalPrice}>${totalPrice} total</p>
        </div>
        {discount && <p className={style.discount}>Save {discount}%</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubscriptionCard;
```

```
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import './UpgradeAccountAction.scss';
import {default as style} from './UpgradeAccountAction.scss.json';
import ActionSheet from './ui/forms/ActionSheet';
import {Button} from './ui/forms/Button';
import {Typography} from './ui/forms/Typography';
import {Server} from 'lincd-server-utils/lib/utils/Server';
import {packageName} from '../package';
import useState from 'react-usestateref';
import {useAuth} from 'lincd-auth/lib/hooks/useAuth';
import {FeatureCounter} from 'lincd-dating/lib/shapes/FeatureCounter';
import {on} from 'events';
import SubscriptionCard from './SubscriptionCard';
import Divider from './Divider';

const SUBSCRIPTION_DATA = [
  {
    id: 0,
    month: 1,
    monthlyPrice: 24.99,
    totalPrice: 24.99,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    month: 6,
    monthlyPrice: 12.5,
    totalPrice: 74.99,
    discount: 50,
    review: 'Popular',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    month: 12,
    monthlyPrice: 8.33,
    totalPrice: 99.99,
    discount: 67,
    review: 'Best value',
  },
];

interface UpgradeAccountActionProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onUpgraded: () => Promise<boolean>;
  onClose: () => void;
}
export const UpgradeAccountAction = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  onUpgraded,
}: UpgradeAccountActionProps) => {
  const defaultSelectedCard = SUBSCRIPTION_DATA[0];
  const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(defaultSelectedCard);

  const auth = useAuth();

  console.log('selectedCard', selectedCard);

  return (
    <ActionSheet isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      <div className={style.pageContainer}>
        <div className={style.header}>
          <div className={style.iconContainer}>
            <img src="images/sp-premium.svg" alt="sp premium icon" />
          </div>
          <h1>Spiritual Premium</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={style.contentContainer}>
          <h2>
            See Who Lies You and match with them instantly with Spiritual
            Premium™️.
          </h2>
          <div className={style.carouselContainer}>
            <p>Select a plan</p>
            <div className={style.cardCarousel}>
              {SUBSCRIPTION_DATA.map((data, i) => {
                return (
                  <SubscriptionCard
                    isSelected={selectedCard.id === i}
                    onSelect={() => setSelectedCard(SUBSCRIPTION_DATA[i])}
                    month={data.month}
                    monthlyPrice={data.monthlyPrice}
                    totalPrice={data.totalPrice}
                    discount={data.discount}
                    review={data.review}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <Divider text="or" />
          <div className={style.benefits}>
            <h6>Included with Spiritual Premium™️</h6>
            <ul>
              <li>Unlimited Likes</li>
              <li>See Who Likes You</li>
              <li>1 Free Boost per month</li>
              <li>5 Free Quantum Likes per week</li>
              <li>
                <p>Passport</p>
                <p>Match and chat with people anywhere in the world.</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p>Top Picks</p>
                <p>Browse through a daily curated selection of profile.</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p>Control Your Profile </p>
                <p>Only show what you want them to know.</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p>Control Who Sees You</p>
                <p>Manage who you’re seen by.</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p>Control Who You See</p>
                <p>Choose the type of people you want to connect with.</p>
              </li>
              <li>Hide Ads</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <footer className={style.footer}>
          <div className={style.footerWrapper}>
            <p className={style.footerWrapper__top}>
              By tapping Continue, you will be charged, your subscription will
              auto-renew for the same price and package length until you cancel
              via App Store settings, and you agree to our <a href="#">Terms</a>
              .
            </p>
            {/* fullwidth */}
            {/* <Button fullWidth={true} className={style.continueBtn}>
            Continue
          </Button> */}
            <div className={style.footerWrapper__bottom}>
              <div className={style.footerWrapper__left}>
                <img src="images/sp-premium.svg" alt="sp premium icon" />
                <div className={style.text}>
                  <p>{selectedCard.month} Month</p>
                  <p>${selectedCard.totalPrice} total</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <Button
                className={style.footerWrapper__right}
                onClick={onUpgraded}
              >
                Continue
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </ActionSheet>
  );
};
```

Comment: have you tried using scrollintoview method?

Comment: @RaoAsim thank you for the idea (i didnt know there was this kinda method)! i ended up using the similar method which is scrollTo()